# How to SELECT lines when their first x characters are identical and output the data of one of their rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called *entries*. The rows are: *member*, *id*, *title* and *added*

I need from phpMyAdmin a list of the cases when the "title" starts with the same 20 strings (after this the end varies), and to know which are the "member" values for whom they are registered.

The best I can do myself (sorry!) Is to output a generic list of EVERY entry, and manually search, with my eyes, the cases when the title starts with the same characters:

```
SELECT title, member FROM (
SELECT * FROM entries
ORDER BY added
DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
) AS olitest
ORDER BY title
```

Some form of LEFT (ID, 20) should come into play... But that's beyond my skill.
Do you see how that could be done?

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you want the results to look like.

Comment: i wonder if this is a regex question or a group by, as Gordon has pounded out. also, consider removing the phpmyadmin tag from this question

Comment: To answer to you, Drew Pierce, I wrote in my question that this is to be done with phpmyadmin, using mysql. Ought I to edit it to make it even clearer ? (no sarcasm) Anyway, I can write it again, that rules out regex.

Comment: And to answer to Gordon, I don't need answers in a very strict format. Anything that works is a worthy basis :) Eventually, I'm wanting to find the cases when different members have titles that look like they're identical, that's it.

Comment: I agree with @DrewPierce that this isn't really a phpMyAdmin question as such; you're doing something in MySQL, using phpMyAdmin as your interface, but the question would be the same whether you're using the command line client, MySQL Workbench, or any other tool to access MySQL.

Comment: had @IsaacBennetch not at-signed me i would never have been brought back to this page. might wanna do that in top comment section (up here) if you want peeps to know you were providing feedback. Gordon of course sees your comments below cuz it is under his Answer. btw i love sarcasm especially directed at me

Answer (score 2):

If you want all titles that share the first 20 characters, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select left(e.title, 20), group_concat(title) as titles
from entries e
group by left(e.title, 20)
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you only, say, wanted a count and a sample row, you could use `max()`:

```
select left(e.title, 20), count(*), max(title) 
from entries e
group by left(e.title, 20)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I realize too late my question was poorly written and missing out on important details, but I already tried to work with the code you provided. In that case, it is missing on another important piece of information, the member name... Still, I already learnt stuff, so thank you!